# unplug the laptop battery when the laptop is working

Tags: laptop, battery, dell-inspiron, battery-life

I usually plug the charger to my laptop, whiles my battery is plugged in. After a while, when my battery became fully charged I remove it from laptop, while the laptop is still working.

Now I want know is it harmful to my battery that I remove it while the laptop is working?

My laptop is *Dell Inspiron 5520*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the situation and on the model you use, but in general:

- If you're Laptop is still plugged-in: No harm (in most cases - depends on the model)
- If you're running on battery, don't do it. Correct shutdown always to recommend

*(Remark Battery Lifecycle): Do not fully charge them to store, best for LIPO batteries is to keep them at about 80% for storage. So remove them before fully charged. Another thing: do not discharge completely - stay in the 40% to 80% and your battery will have a long life.*